# Can not get signed in email using Office 365 REST API

Tags: outlook, oauth-2.0, office365, office365api, office365-restapi

I followed this post http://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/2142 and Ruby to get user's email address. Here is the code:

```js
# Parses an ID token and returns the user's email
def get_email_from_id_token(id_token)

  # JWT is in three parts, separated by a '.'
  token_parts = id_token.split('.')
  # Token content is in the second part
  encoded_token = token_parts[1]

  # It's base64, but may not be padded
  # Fix padding so Base64 module can decode
  leftovers = token_parts[1].length.modulo(4)
  if leftovers == 2
    encoded_token += '=='
  elsif leftovers == 3
    encoded_token += '='
  end

  # Base64 decode (urlsafe version)
  decoded_token = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(encoded_token)

  # Load into a JSON object
  jwt = JSON.parse(decoded_token)

  # Email is in the 'preferred_username' field
  email = jwt['preferred_username']
end
```

This function worked very well, I can get user's email address. But today, this function still works without error but the JSON I got not contain user's email address anymore. 
Could someone help me? I want to get user's email address. Thank you !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Azure deployed a breaking change to the v2 app model, and you don't get user info by default anymore.

You can read all about it here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-preview-oidc-changes/, but to summarize:

- The `openid` scope *used* to give you basic profile info for the user.
- That wasn't in line with the OpenID standard
- Azure changed to require that you request the `profile` scope to get access to that information

For that sample, find this bit:

```
# Scopes required by the app
SCOPES = [ 'openid',
           'https://outlook.office.com/mail.read' ]
```

And change it to:

```
# Scopes required by the app
SCOPES = [ 'openid',
           'profile',
           'https://outlook.office.com/mail.read' ]
```

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. I will try it when I come to company tomorrow.

Comment: Hi we're using the API to grab calendar events and then the email associated with said event.  Do we now have to sign up for a paid account to get this?

Comment: No not at all, you just need to add the `profile` scope. The "for free" comment was referring to getting the info without asking for it :)

Answer (score 2):

Please add profile and email in your scope :

SCOPES = [ 'openid',
           'profile',
           'email',
           'https://outlook.office.com/mail.read' ]

Comment: If I dont use mail.read I am not able to get the users' profile info, I dont want to ask for mail read permission